# constructor overloading creating confusion

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, std, stdmap

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define mpq pair<int,Query>
using namespace std;

class Query{
    public:
    int a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d,l,r;
    Query(){}
    Query(int a1,int a2,int b1,int b2,int c1,int c2,int d,int l,int r){
        this->a1=a1; this->a2=a2;
        this->b1=b1; this->b2=b2;
        this->c1=c1; this->c2=c2;
        this->d=d; this->l=l; this->r=r;
        print();
    }
    Query(int d,int l,int r){
        Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,d,l,r);
    }

    void print(){
        cout<<d<<" "<<l<<" "<<r<<endl;
    }
};

map<int,Query> query;
int main(){
    query.insert(mpq(1,Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)));
    query[1].print();
    cout<<endl;

    query[4]=Query(4,4,4);//not working properly
    query[4].print();//giving output of query[1].print
    cout<<endl;

    query[2]=Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,2,2,2);
    query[2].print();

}
```

I am unable to explain the output of this code
`query[4].print()` is giving unexpected output

I was expecting output to be

> 4 4 4

but it is giving

> 1 1 1

as output

Comment: don't use #define in c++ if typedef fits the usecase better:
typedef std::pair<int,Query> mpg;

Comment: The first three lines of this code are all bad practices. There is no standard header named "bits/stdc++.h"; text macros like that one are accidents waiting to happen (use a `typedef`); and `using namespace std;` will bite you sooner or later (use `std::cout`). And while I'm at it, do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
Query(int d,int l,int r){
    Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,d,l,r);
}
```

Doesn't do anything. `Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,d,l,r);` create a temporary `Query` and then destroys it.  I think you meant to use a delegating constructor and that would look like

```
Query(int d,int l,int r) : Query(0,1,0,1,0,1,d,l,r) {}
```